# What is the part where a seed starts growing called?

Tags: seeds, terminology

Is it *hilum*?

Is this a common word? I'm looking for a word that a layman can understand. I'm not native in English, so I don't know which word to use.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilum_(biology)):

> On a bean seed, the hilum is called the "eye".

My seed is malabar chestnut. Can I call the white dot on top the "eye", or "hilum" if it's understood by most people?

[image: seed pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the hilum is not the point of the seed where it grows. It is actually a scar, the place it was attached to the mother plant (compare it with the navel in humans).

Technically there are more points where a normal seed would grow, if you look here at the [anatomy](https://www.toppr.com/guides/biology/anatomy-of-flowering-plants/the-seed/) of a seed. You can see that the epicotyl will grow to become the shoots above ground, and the radicle will grow into roots in the ground.

Comment: I'm looking for the place where the root starts growing. So is it *radicle*? I guess most people understand the word, right?

Comment: Yeah that's radicle. I think 99.9% of the people have never heard of the word radicle.

Comment: OK I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Good question, good answer, and good comments; maybe just call it: the place where the sprout grows out from the seed.  :)

Comment: Thank you for your question! Welcome to the site!